# Empty Mix Sonos Custom Error Handling

Tags: sonos

Our clients have the possibility to day-part their customised mixes. That is, to set a starting and finishing times. If you try to play a mix when it is off-hours you won't be returned any song, but instead a customised error message should pop up. 
While programming, following the indications in your musicpartners website, we dealt with this situation by raising a Customised Soap Fault that looks like:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <faultcode>Client.EmptyMix</faultcode>
     <faultstring>SoapException</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ExceptionInfo>There are currently no songs to play. Mix is empty or off-hours</ExceptionInfo>
        <SonosError>1</SonosError>
     </detail>
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But when accessing a mix off-hours with Sonos, instead of showing our mix off-hours message it says "Connection with SOUNDMACHINE was lost".

Comment: Have you created a strings.xml file with an error message corresponding to the error code. You need a string named Error1Message. See http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/218 for details.

Comment: I added now the error message in the strings.xml, but now I don't see any message in Sonos when the error is raised. Do I need to increase the string.xml version and submit a new build version in musicpartners?

Comment: Yes you will need to increment the strings.xml version on your service.  If you have added the service through customsd.htm you can re-add it with service id number and a higher strings.xml version.

Answer (score 0):

I am consolidating the comments above into the answer field to capture everything.

In order to surface custom error messages, you have to create them in the strings.xml file.   Your **NUMERICVALUE** corresponds with the string named Error**NUMERICVALUE**Message. See musicpartners.sonos.com/node/218 for details.  For example…

There are currently no songs to play. Mix is empty or off-hours
        1

Would mean that Error1Message is equal to the string "There are currently no songs to play. Mix is empty or off-hours”.

Once you modify this file, you need to increment the version number associated with Strings.xml so it will be reloaded.